# Как переписать функцию используюя ListView Django

Tags: python, django

никак не могу переписать функцию представления используя ListView generic.

Дано:

```
    def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})
```

Пытаюсь переписать..но получается, отфильтровать товары по категории

```
    class ProductList(ListView):
        model = Product
        template_name = 'shop/product/list.html'
    
        def get_context_data(self, *, category_slug=None, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['category'] = None
            context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
            context['products'] = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
            if category_slug:
                category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
                context['products'] = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
            return context
```

мои модели:

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='URL')
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products', verbose_name='Категория')
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')
```